# Spring HATEOAS - Building a Robust and Scalable Solution

Tags: java, spring, rest, hateoas, spring-hateoas

Let's consider that I have a REST controller with 3 services.  I have the following code in place to add links to each other:

```
@RestController
public class ServiceController {


  @RequestMapping("/service1")
  public HttpEntity<Response> service1() {

      Response response = new Response("You are in service 1");

      response.add(linkTo(methodOn(ServiceController.class).service1()).withSelfRel());
      response.add(linkTo(methodOn(ServiceController.class).service2()).withRel("service2"));
      response.add(linkTo(methodOn(ServiceController.class).service3()).withRel("service3"));

      return new ResponseEntity<Response>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
  }

  @RequestMapping("/service2")
  public HttpEntity<Response> service2() {

      Response response = new Response("You are in service 2");

      response.add(linkTo(methodOn(ServiceController.class).service1()).withRel("service1"));
      response.add(linkTo(methodOn(ServiceController.class).service2()).withSelfRel());
      response.add(linkTo(methodOn(ServiceController.class).service3()).withRel("service3"));

      return new ResponseEntity<Response>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
  }

  @RequestMapping("/service3")
  public HttpEntity<Response> service3() {

      Response response = new Response("You are in service 3");

      response.add(linkTo(methodOn(ServiceController.class).service1()).withRel("service1"));
      response.add(linkTo(methodOn(ServiceController.class).service2()).withRel("service2"));
      response.add(linkTo(methodOn(ServiceController.class).service3()).withSelfRel());

      return new ResponseEntity<Response>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
  }
}
```

While this works, it's not very robust or scalable.  Every time I have to modify/delete a service, I have to find all of the instances of it and change it.  And if I create a new service, I'm going to have to copy a link to that new service to services 1 - 3.  (Additionally, there is also a good amount of duplicate code.)

What is the best way to refactor this code?  Would it make sense to move this linking code outside of the services altogether?

Comment: Simply extract the duplicate into a separate method. Not really a Spring HATEOAS question.

Comment: Sure, but I'd still run into the same issues with scalability. Every time I'm creating/modifying/deleting a method, I'm going to have to find all instances and update. This is a very simple example,  but in reality I've got a number of methods with very different parameters based on the entry point.